# Electrostatic Energy

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics

We all know that electrostatic PE between 2 point charges is kq1×q2/r.But what is PE between a hollow uniformly charged sphere of radius R and charge Q ??

Answer (score 1):

It is the exact same. Try to use Gauss' Law to find the electric field of a uniform sphere.